# How to port forward for DynDNS without touching the NAT router

Tags: vpn, portforwarding, nat, dyndns

I got a bit of a problem lately. I want to access my home network from the internet using a VPN and DynDNS.
For DynDNS I registered a free domain name at TwoDNS. My router is also setup to tell the DNS server its current IP address once in a while.
But then I realized that the address shown at TwoDNS doesn't match the address my router has. This is due to the fact that I am living at a student residence that is connected to the network of our university.

So my local network probably lies behind multiple NAT-routers. Usually this would require a port forward but how if I am not in control of the routers.
Maybe an external server with a constant connection to my home network will do the trick. What do you think?

**Is there some kind of dynamic NAT?**

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple and there is one specific service to enable just what I described: **LogMeIn Hamachi**